# Exclude keywords from an empty query in Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

**Is it possible to exclude certain keywords from an empty query through Sphinx?**

What I had in mind is to use the Extended2 match mode, and in order to exclude keywords, I'll be using the `-` or `!` operator. I only need to fetch data through Sphinx without using any query (except for the exclusion operators).

In Sphinx, I fetch data using the following method:

```
$data = $sphinx->query('');
```

This query returns data which doesn't have to match anything (it means it'll return all data, and of course limited to the query limit). The problem is, if I add a keyword with the ! or - operator, it doesn't return anything. For instance:

```
$data = $sphinx->query('-google');
```

`$data` is returned as `false`

Maybe there is another method for this to work. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx doesnt like negation only queries. If you check GetLastError()/GetLastWarning() it will explicitly say so.

The main reason, is it can't efficently use its index. Sphinx is based on the concept of inverted indexes. So to run this query, it needs to fetch a list of every document, then remove the ones matching the keyword.

But you make it work. Just need to give sphinx a keyword that will be in every single document. Then can just do

```
$data = $sphinx->query('popularword -google');
```

If you dont have a word taht will be every document, just add a fake one :)

```
sql_query = SELECT id, '__ALL__' as dummy, title .......
```

can then just do

```
$data = $sphinx->query('__ALL__ -google');
```

As the word will be on every document.

Dont expect the query to be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

As far as know it is not possible. Sphinx will fail at computing any query that involves searching through an entire collection.

For both options allowing you to use `-`, it is explicitly stated in the documentation that is is impossible:

[SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/boolean-syntax.html):

> Queries like "-dog", which implicitly include all documents from the collection, can not be evaluated.

[SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/extended-syntax.html):

> However, the query must be possible to compute without involving an implicit list of all documents

Short answer is: no, it is not possible. The only alternative is if you want to implement this for a small list of keywords, then you can add in your database a flag and set the value to `true` if the text contains this keyword. You'll be able to exclude them with a `SetFilter()` from your search results. I'm using this trick to exclude documents containing a certain set of keywords from my listings.